# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined at window.onhashchange

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have html code:

```
<ul id="nav" class="site-main-menu">
        <!-- About Me Subpage link -->
        <li>
            <a class="pt-trigger" href="/" data-animation="58" data-goto="1">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pt-trigger" href="/blog" data-animation="58" data-goto="1">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pt-trigger" href="/article" data-animation="61" data-goto="1">Article</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pt-trigger" href="/about" data-animation="59" data-goto="1">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pt-trigger" href="/contact" data-animation="59" data-goto="1">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html") 

@app.route("/blog", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def labs():
     return render_template("blog.html")

@app.route("/article", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def studios():
     return render_template("article.html")

@app.route("/about", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def about():
     return render_template("about.html")
```

then I got error in js like this:

[image]

why if on html code, when I use 'href="/blog"' always appear error message on console log, and the effect is my animation not working.
but if I use 'href="#blog"', my animation is working, but cannot call python def.

Comment: But if I using 'href="#blog"', cannot call def in python file.

Comment: Add your code as code, not images.

Comment: Remove the python code and add the javascript code as that is what is giving the error.

Comment: are u have an example the javascript code for call python def?
because in my def for call every page.

Comment: case closed,
thank's for everyone